# Strange behaviour when adding Options to Protected symbols

Tags: options, optional-arguments, protect

I want to use the `TensorProduct` function to work for some of my custom expressions with head `FusionRing` and I want it to be able to take optional arguments.

Defining the product is easily done using upvalues, but when I want to define options, something strange happens.

The following code

```
Quit[]
```

```
Unprotect[TensorProduct];

Options[TensorProduct] = {"a" -> 1};

Protect[TensorProduct];
```

results in a warning: "Tag TensorProduct in Options[TensorProduct] is Protected" and `Options[TensorProduct]` returns `{}`.

The following code

```
Quit
```

```
Options[TensorProduct];

Unprotect[TensorProduct];

Options[TensorProduct] = Options[CreateFusionRing];

Protect[TensorProduct];
```

does not result in a warning and `Options[TensorProduct]` returns `{"a"->1}`.

Can someone explain to me why this behavior occurs?

Comment: You do not need: "Options[TensorProduct];". The second time you evaluate: "Unprotect[TensorProduct];..." it does no more give an error message.

Comment: I know, but why does this happen? At the moment, I still use the Options[TensorProduct] because otherwise, my package gives a warning upon loading...

Comment: My guess is `TensorProduct` is in a file that gets loaded when invoked, and that package has `Protect[TensorProduct]` in its code. In your first example, the `Options[TensorProduct] =...` triggers loading of the package, which undoes your `Unprotect`. In the second one the load happened prior to the `Unprotect`. (Again, this is speculation.)